# Custom column in field relationship in backpack for laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have 3 models. User, role and service.
The role is associated with the user, the user with the service.
When adding a new entry to the service, I also want to add a user. Now it looks like this:

```
[
 'label'     => 'User',
 'type'      => 'relationship',
 'name'      => 'users',
 'entity'    => 'users',
 'attribute' => 'name',
 'ajax'      => true,
 'minimum_input_length'  => 0,
],
```

Trait FetchOperation looks like this:

```
public function fetchUsers()
    {
        return $this->fetch([
            'model' => Users::class,
            'searchable_attributes' => ['name'],
            'paginate' => 10,
            'query' => function ($model) {
                $search = request()->input('q') ?? false;
                if ($search){
                    return $model->where('users.name', 'like', "%$search%");
                }else{
                    return $model;
                }
            }
        ]);
    }
```

It's work. I would like the search bar to display the role name and username for example: admin | John. But only the user name was added to the attribute.
For example

```
public function fetchUsers()
        {
            return $this->fetch([
                'model' => Users::class,
                'searchable_attributes' => [],
                'paginate' => 10,
                'query' => function ($model) {
                    $search = request()->input('q') ?? false;
                    if ($search){
                        return $model->selectRaw('Concat(role.name," | ", users.name) as custom_value, users.name as name')
->leftJoin('role', ...)
->where('users.name', 'like', "%$search%");
                    }else{
                        return $model;
                    }
                }
            ]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an acessor in model like:

```php
public function getRoleAndNameAttribute() {
    return $this->role->name . '|' . $this->name;
}
```

And in your select define the attribute as `attribute => 'roleAndName'`.

Edit: add it to your model `$appends` property.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, thanks, I already found the solution. Your answer is not complete, but partially correct.

Comment: Do you happen to know why an accessor works fine with append attributes, but a mutator doesn't?

Comment: See like this, Acessor is for  Reading while Mutator is for writting. 

$appends is for Reading only. If you want to do something custom when the model is created you can use model events like the `created`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added a field to $fillable so that the mutator could work, and then unset the virtual attribute.